# icCube - How to create Excel compatible thousands formatting?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I have an icCube report where I want "1500000" to be formatted as "1,500K".

If I set `FORMAT_STRING="#,##0\K,"`, the formatting works in icCube but not in the exported Excel sheet. If I set `FORMAT_STRING="#,##0,\K"`, the formatting works in the exported Excel sheet but not in icCube.

How can I specify a FORMAT_STRING that works for both Excel and icCube?

I'm using icCube version 7.10.

**Steps to Reproduce Formatting Mismatch**

1. Run the following query from the icCube MDX debugger:

   ```
    WITH
      CALCULATED MEMBER [WorksInIcCube] AS 1500000, FORMAT_STRING="#,##0\K,"
      CALCULATED MEMBER [WorksInExcel] AS 1500000, FORMAT_STRING="#,##0,\K"
    SELECT {[WorksInIcCube],[WorksInExcel]} ON 0
    FROM [MyCube]
    CELL PROPERTIES STYLE, CLASSNAME, VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
   ```

   This will create an icCube table where WorksInIcCube is formatted as `1,500K` and WorksInExcel is formatted as `1500000`.
2. Click the "Export the MDX result to Excel" button and open the exported file in Excel. In Excel, WorksInIcCube is formatted as `1,500,00K,` and WorksInExcel is formatted as `1,500K`.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the behavior FORMAT_STRING="#,##0,\K" (assuming you're seeing 1500K in Excel) in Excel.

How are you exporting your MDX result? From the MDX IDE or from the Reporting (which widget?)?

Comment: If I set the formatting to `#,##0,\K`, the number is displayed as 1500000 in the icCube table and 1,500K in Excel. I am exporting the Excel file from a Table widget in the Reporting view.

I can see in the exported Excel file that the custom cell formatting is set to `#,##0,K`.

Comment: You mean a Pivot Table ? Where are you defining that FORMAT_STRING ? Can you reproduce with a very simple MDX statement please.

Comment: I was exporting the data from a pivot table in the report view, but I can also reproduce the formatting issue in the MDX debugger. Please see the steps in the updated description.